# Como Fazer com que um code jquery seja executado somente na versão desktop do site

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte problema no código abaixo:

```
// Muda o menu de imagem pra texto
    var x = $(window).width();

        if(x >= 590){
            $(document).on("scroll",function(){

                    if($(document).scrollTop()>100){ //QUANDO O SCROLL PASSAR DOS 100px DO TOPO
                        $("#nav_logo_img").removeClass("imgON").addClass("imgnone");
                        $("#nav_logo_texto").addClass("logo_textoON").fadeIn();
                        $("nav").addClass("nav_pequeno").addClass("bg_navbar");
                    } else{
                        $("#nav_logo_img").removeClass("imgnone").addClass("imgON");
                        $("#nav_logo_texto").removeClass("logo_textoON").fadeOut();
                        $("nav").removeClass("nav_pequeno").removeClass("bg_navbar");
                    }

            });
        }else{
            // não muda nada
        }
```

Esse code e para que o navbar ao passar de 100px diminua de tamanho, e troque a cor e a logo do site, isso ta funcionando 100%. O problema e que na versão mobile o texto já aparece por padrão, mais o code acima faz com que a logo pisque na tela, Tentei usar um if para mudar isso na versão mobile mais não to conseguindo, sem alguém puder me dar uma luz em como fazer esse efeito aparecer no na versão desktop??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a questão é apenas limitar a execução do código em desktop, podes usar a biblioteca (são só 4K):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ismobilejs@0.5.1/dist/isMobile.min.js"></script>
```

Depois no teu javascript, em vez de ter o if por windows width podes colocar logo por !isMobile.any

O código ficava algo assim:

```
if(!isMobile.any){
        $(document).on("scroll",function(){

                if($(document).scrollTop()>100){ //QUANDO O SCROLL PASSAR DOS 100px DO TOPO
                    $("#nav_logo_img").removeClass("imgON").addClass("imgnone");
                    $("#nav_logo_texto").addClass("logo_textoON").fadeIn();
                    $("nav").addClass("nav_pequeno").addClass("bg_navbar");
                } else{
                    $("#nav_logo_img").removeClass("imgnone").addClass("imgON");
                    $("#nav_logo_texto").removeClass("logo_textoON").fadeOut();
                    $("nav").removeClass("nav_pequeno").removeClass("bg_navbar");
                }

        });
    }else{
        // não muda nada
    }
```

Comment: bgd, funcionou certinho!